# How to create complex views in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, view, temp-tables

I am trying to create a view (Result) from another source view (which already has multiple joins from different tables and group by functions) implementing complex functions.

I have two approaches here:

1. Create a view directly from the source view; this is taking a very long time to execute since there are many group by and joins multiple times for each column
2. Create a temporary table based on the results from source view and create my result view from this temporary table; SQL Server is not allowing to create views from a temporary table.

Any advice or different approach I could use?

Comment: DO NOT create a view that uses another view. It will cripple your server. https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/performance/the-seven-sins-against-tsql-performance/#seven The best approach would be to create this view independently of any other views. Seems counterintuitive but that is the reality.

Comment: Sean is correct.  And I'd add the classic "it depends".  There's a rule of thumb I go by: max 7 joins (and no joins to views).  For more than 7 joins, use temp tables as you suggest.  But then you'll need a stored procedure, not a view.

Comment: What kind of strange rule is "max 7 joins"??? And joining to views is perfectly fine, just not nesting views.

Comment: @SeanLange I think he meant no joining to views in your view, which is the same as nesting views.

Comment: @TabAlleman that could be. Curious about the "max 7 joins" thing. This is not something I have ever heard before.

Comment: Thanks all ! Based on your comments, we decided to create my view directly from base tables since it takes the least time :)